# How to get a Tracking_ID in Google Analytics for iOS apps for Google Tag Manager usage?

Tags: ios, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I've set up my account in Google Analytics, Google Tag Manager and have already installed firebase/analytics and GoogleTagManager to my project...

The problem is when I go the admin section and click on the default property created for my app I have no Tracking_ID on property settings menu, 
the property is set as `app + web` I've tried to set a new property as `App` it then gives me only a `.plist` and no Tracking_ID for managing the events on Google Tag Manager...

Is google tag manager a tool meant to be used only for web now?
Because I installed it on iOS but it seems GA doesn't provide Tracking_ID for mobile tracking and without Tracking_ID I just can't use GTM...

Any help on this matter would be highly appreciated,
Thank you all in advance)

Answer (score 1):

GA App properties were sunsetted and are now app+web properties.

In GA for the Property you created, you also need to add a data stream. App+Web Properties use a Measurement ID, not a Tracking ID.

> When you add an app data stream, Analytics creates a corresponding
>   Firebase project and app data stream, and automatically links the
>   Firebase project to your property if your project and property are not
>   already linked. **Currently, you cannot link to an existing Firebase
>   project from Analytics.**
>
> Enter the iOS bundle ID or Android package name, the app name, and for
>   iOS, the App Store ID, then click Register app.
>
> Analytics will progress through the steps of creating a Google Cloud
>   project, a Firebase project, linking the Firebase project to
>   Analytics, and creating the app stream. Click Next.
>
> Follow the instructions to download the config file for your app. Click Next.
>
> Follow the instructions to add the Firebase SDK to your app. Click Next.
>
> Run your app to verify installation of the SDK and that the app is communicating with Google servers. Click Finish.
>
> Alternatively, click Skip this step if you want to complete app setup
>   at a later time.  Click Next.
>   **Ref:** https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9304153

GTM also has two new tags in it - GA App+Web Configuration tag & GA App+Web Event.